# How to cheat the SVN client version used to checkout a working copy

Tags: eclipse, svn, maven

I am working with on a project managed with Subversion.
I am using the Subclipse plugin for that : (v1.6.16)
He is the one that did the checkout for me.

Now, I need to run some command line stuff on Maven (the Release plugin BTW), that calls a command line version of SVN. 
For that, I have downloaded the SlikSVN Windows package (the last version v1.6.13).

However, Maven is complaining (with good reason I would say) that my subversion client is too old for my working copy.

Here is the message I get :

> [INFO] Unable to commit files Provider
>   message: The svn command failed.
>   Command output: svn: This client is
>   too old to work with working copy
>   'D:\Users\raphael\eclipse-workspace\base-lib';
>   please get a newer Subversion client

I guess that 1.6.13 to 1.6.16 might be some very minor changes.
Where does SVN actually store the version number he used for the checkout ?
I would like to trick him into thinking I actually used a 1.6.13 client.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Raphaël

Comment: If they require new version they probably have a good reason for it. I would consider updating to newer version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double-check that your SlikSVN 1.6.13 client is actually in the PATH. My guess is you have a copy of Subversion 1.4 or 1.5 in the PATH, and that is what's screwing up the operation for Maven.

As far as I know, working copy formats do not change within a major version. You don't want to trick svn, you just need to make sure the right version is available for Maven (Any version of 1.6 should do - it shouldn't be particular about 1.6.13 vs 1.6.11)

Comment: You were right.
I had a 1.4 version in the PATH.
Finally, I used the version from WANDisco (http://www.wandisco.com/subversion/os/downloads) which was up to date (1.6.15).
Cheating is bad anyway !

Answer (score 1):

It sounds that you misconfigured the Subclipse Plugin not to use the newest release. Take a look into the configuration. Windows -> Preferences -> Team -> SVN -> SVN Interface (be sure to set this to SVNKit 1.3.X). This might be the problem.

Have you called

```
svn --version
```

on command line ? There you get the information about the version of the installed SVN client.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you cannot achieve this because the SVN version gets actually sent by client (i.e. the output of `svn --version` and is not stored anywhere outside the program.